# How to handle errors of same type globally?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, error-handling

The Below code is only to explain the purpose of my question, and not to write a code to answer it.

**page1.ts**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
    import { AuthData } from '../../app/provider/authdata.service';
    import { SignUp } from '../signup/signup';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import { ResetPage } from '../reset/reset';
    import { Push, PushToken } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';
    import { Mixpanel,GoogleAnalytics  } from 'ionic-native';

    //import {Formsmodule} from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
        selector: 'page-login',
        templateUrl: 'login.html',

    })

    export class Login {
        public email: string;
        public password: string;

        constructor(public nav: NavController, public authData: AuthData,public push:Push) { }


        loginUser() {

            this.authData.loginUser(this.email, this.password).then(
                () => this.nav.setRoot(HomePage),
                (error) => console.log('unable to load HomePage' + error.message));

        }

doSomething(){
this.authData.doSomeWork();
}


        myClick1() {
            console.log('it is in SignUp');
            this.nav.setRoot(SignUp);
        }

    }
```

I have a service class named **authdata.service.ts**, which contains a series of functions such as **login, signup, do something** etc.Which in turn makes a REST API calls to the server.
So, In the UI I try to make a call to any of these functions that finally makes a req to REST API, and throws back some error response(note: error response will be same for all these functions) and I want to handle that in the UI, so I put an alert controller in one of those functions, then I realise that it will be needed in other functions too.

**Question1**: Instead to write code in all the functions and catching them and using an alert controller is there any better way that exists, so that I can handle the same types of errors globally and write the code only once?Please suggest some references or some descriptions.

Using ionic2 as a framework.

Comment: no one will do code for you. Do something first then post your question on SO. Its to help community, no one will work for you.

Comment: Now that looks good .